# tablerow background color doesn't work with tabledata #css

Tags: css, background-color

so I'm new in HTML and CSS, but I have to do some "work" for my school subject.
The idea is to create some sort of chess board by using colors of even/odd cells in the table, also I can't edit the .html file.

[This is how it should looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c4hW.png)

[And that's my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzTyl.png)

```
table tr:nth-child(even){
background-color: #9c9c9c;
}
table td:nth-child(odd){
background-color: #ffffff;
}
table td:nth-child(even){
background-color: #c8ccc6;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color: #d8dbd7;
}
```

There is no wonder that i did something wrong, but i really don't know what tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Just target the td and tr to set the initial color, then target the psuedo `nth-child(odd)` / `(even)` and set its bg color. This will give you the checkered look.

```css
tr td {
    background-color: #9c9c9c;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), 
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d8dbd7;
}
```

So on every **even** indexed row, the **odd** table data cell will be styled, then on every **odd** indexed row, the **even** data-cell will be styled. Each one not falling into the nth-child styling will default to the tr/td style.

```css
tr td {
    background-color: #9c9c9c;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), 
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #d8dbd7;
}
```

```html
<table width="50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Place</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>3rd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>2nd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>4th</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Billy</td>
    <td>Bly</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>1st</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, well your idea is quite good, but I need to use 4 different colors, for instance: td even-gray td odd-light gray, tr even- white tr odd- dark gray. That could be my bad if i didn't say it clearly in the topic :v

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, if anyone would struggle with similar problem, here's the answer for that. I had to put this in front of css.

```
:root {
    --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --light-gray: rgb(240, 240, 240); 
    --gray: rgb(197, 197, 197); 
    --dark-gray: rgb(136, 136, 136);

    --tbl-hover: rgba(156, 57, 153, 0.5);

    --selection-clr: rgb(156, 57, 153);   
}
```

And then add

```
/* gray*/
tr:nth-child(odd),
tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: var(--gray);
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover,
tr:nth-child(odd):hover td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(156, 57, 153, 0.6);
}


/* darkgray*/
tr:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: var(--dark-gray);
}

tr:nth-child(even):hover,
tr:nth-child(even):hover td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(156, 57, 153, 0.8);
}


 /* white */
tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: var(--white);
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}


/* lightgray */
tr:nth-child(even) > td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--light-gray);
}

tr:nth-child(even):hover td:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}


/* white for <th> */
th:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: var(--white);
}

tr:nth-child(odd):hover th:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```